# Save ListView Item and use it in another ListView?

Tags: android, listview, favorites

I am trying to create add to Favorites function. I have 2 `ListView`'s, 1 normal and 1 for favorites. For example, if user wants to add to favorites some item from normal `ListView` I want to take data from that `ListView` Row and show it in Favorites `Listview.` What is the way to do this? 
The ListView is using Array Adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you post some code?

Either way, basically what you do is: Get the selected item from your first `ListView` and add it to the `ArrayAdapter` of the second `ListView`.

Once you've done that you call the `notifyDataSetChanged` on the second `ListView`

Edit:

A good link for basic options of data storage in Android: [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: But I want to save that. So when user leaves app it doesn't go away, also when user comes back to see that same list.

Comment: You will need to use a way to save your data then too, take a look at `SQLite` for android. So you can add your item to the database and get it back when the activity loads.

Comment: Or as you said, if your `ListView` only contains basic variables (String, int, boolean,...) you could use `SharedPreferences` although I would still recommend a database or file storage.

Comment: But is it safe? Memory is what worries me.

Comment: Have a look at this link: [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) It's a basic start and a decent list of ways to save data on android.

Answer (score 0):

Just take the index of `ArrayList` which you select and put that index's value in an another `ArrayList`.Then just fill your 2nd `ListView` with the stored `ArrayList`

this will work..

Comment: And how to save it? Is it safe to use SharedPreferences? or should I use some other methods

Comment: I hope you are using a ArrayList<String/Java Bean Class>. So just define two different ArrayList of same type. When you click on 1st Listview item just get the Index and put that whole 1st ArrayList item to 2nd ArrayList. And when you open the favorite view just inflate your ListView with that 2nd ArrayList